# Как правильно инициализировать объект java?

Tags: java

```
public class Test {
  private List<Strign> asd=new ArrayList<>();
  public Test(List<String> asd){
    this.asd=asd;
  }
}
```

Можно ли так писать код? Будет ли утечка памяти и т.д.?

Comment: писать можно, сборщик мусора удалит первый созданный ArrayList

Comment: @Виктор, Получается правильнее будет инициализацию делать в классе, а не в конструкторе?

Comment: я не скажу как надо, сам не знаю. Но между инциализацией в конструкторе или в классе нет разницы. Разница есть у вас в коде. В классе вы инициализируете пустой лист, а в конструкторе кладете другой (возможно заполненный) лист.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Java так писать можно, утечки памяти не будет, так как в ней есть сборщик мусора, который удаляет объект, когда он не достижим из стека потока. 
Более детально о сборщиках мусора можно прочитать [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/269621/)